# Monitoring change event on dynamically added checkboxes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Using the following code to fire a change event on checkboxes contained in a particular class on the page, but the change event fails to fire on checkboxes that I add dynamically to the class.

```
var Premiuminputs = document.getElementsByClassName('Premium'),
    Premiumtotal  = document.getElementById('Premium'),
    prePremiumTotal = document.getElementById('PremiumTotal');

for (var i=0; i < Premiuminputs.length; i++) {

    document.getElementsByClassName('Premium')[i].onchange = function() {

        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        prePremiumTotal.innerHTML = Number(parseFloat(prePremiumTotal.innerHTML) + add).toFixed(2); 
        //now add shop charges via javascript and put in visible total
        var pre = parseFloat(prePremiumTotal.innerHTML);
        if((pre * .25) > 52.65){
            pre = pre + 52.65
        }else{
            pre += pre * .25;
        }
        Premiumtotal.innerHTML = Number(pre).toFixed(2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you bind the `change` event to the document and then verify the `target.className` when fired, like this:

```
var Premiuminputs = document.getElementsByClassName('Premium'),
    Premiumtotal = document.getElementById('Premium'),
    prePremiumTotal = document.getElementById('PremiumTotal');

document.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if (event.target.className == 'Premium') {
        var el = event.target,
            add = el.value * (el.checked ? 1 : -1);
        prePremiumTotal.innerHTML = Number(parseFloat(prePremiumTotal.innerHTML) + add).toFixed(2);
        //now add shop charges via javascript and put in visible total
        var pre = parseFloat(prePremiumTotal.innerHTML);
        if ((pre * .25) > 52.65) {
            pre = pre + 52.65
        } else {
            pre += pre * .25;
        }
        Premiumtotal.innerHTML = Number(pre).toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

It's supposed to work on any element with `className == 'Premium'`, despite the fact it was created after the DOM is ready.